# Playing sounds on Samsung M220 (Telus Canada) - MIDP 1.0

Tags: java-me, mobile-phones, midp

We're porting some Java applications for the Samsung M220 (Telus). This is a MIDP 1.0 phone and we're stuck when trying to play sounds on it.

As far as I know, MIDP 1.0 does not support our audio functions except system beeps.

Is there any way to play sounds on the M220 (Telus Canada)?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung allows its own proprietary class called the AudioClip(), google it and you will be able to find information on it. Since this being a MIDP 1.0 phone the only api that supports playing sound is the com.samsung.... [don't remember the exact package] AudioClip class.

Hope this helps!